# Calculate signal strength received by an Ultrasonic Transducer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, power

Below is an image showing transducer A transmitting a signal with an amplitude of 3000mV, I am trying to calculate the amplitude of the signal received by transducer B in mV,
I understand that there are dB losses at each of the acoustic interference (1 to 5),

1. Which of the two formulae (given below) are relevant at each of the acoustic
   interference (1 to 5) and why?
2. How are these three parameters related - transmitted signal in mV (transducer A), dB loss and received signal in mV (transducer B)?

I have looked at many articles online, but they haven't helped me. Can someone please suggest me or guide me to help answer the above questions.

[image]

**Formula 1:**
The dB loss of energy on transmitting a signal from medium 1 into medium 2 is given by

[image]

**Formula 2:**
The dB loss of energy of the echo signal in medium 1 reflecting from an interface boundary with medium 2 is given by:

[image]

Comment: The question has been reworded, please review.